# How do I output an integer to an EditText view?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-edittext, output

I have an EditText as input. I am trying to use it for output as well. I've tried the following:

```
FoodIncomeCounter.setText(TotalFood.getText().toString());

FoodIncomeCounter = Integer.parseInt(TotalFood.getText());

String FoodIncomeCounter = String.valueOf(TotalFood);
```

and nothing works. For the 1st and 2nd option the "getText()" cannot be resolved. Am I able to output to an EditText view, or do I need to make a separate TextView and output to that? Hopefully that all makes sense to you. My goal is to be able to use the FoodCampX and FoodUpgradeX variables to calculate the income and output that into FoodIncomeCounter variable/EditText view (which currently you can manually input). FoodIncomeCounter is an EditText view, FoodCampX and FoodUpgradeX and FoodIncome are integers, TotalFood is an integer. Thank you for teaching me.

Here is the code:

```
//to get from user input and into variable form
  
    FoodIncomeCounter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodIncomeCounter);
    IncomeSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IncomeSubmitButton);

    FoodCamp1Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodCamp1Counter);
    FoodCamp2Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodCamp2Counter);
    FoodCamp3Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodCamp3Counter);
    FoodUpgrade1Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodUpgrade1Counter);
    FoodUpgrade2Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodUpgrade2Counter);
    FoodUpgrade3Counter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FoodUpgrade3Counter);
    FoodCampSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FoodCampSubmitButton);

}

    //Buttons
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.IncomeSubmitButton:
                //reset to value
                FoodIncomeCounter.setText("");

                //receive the inputted values
                FoodIncome = Integer.parseInt(FoodIncomeCounter.getText().toString());
                break;
            case R.id.FoodCampSubmitButton:
                //reset to value
                FoodCamp1Counter.setText("");
                FoodCamp2Counter.setText("");
                FoodCamp3Counter.setText("");
                FoodUpgrade1Counter.setText("");
                FoodUpgrade2Counter.setText("");
                FoodUpgrade3Counter.setText("");

                //receive the inputted values
                FoodCamp1 = Integer.parseInt(FoodCamp1Counter.getText().toString());
                FoodCamp2 = Integer.parseInt(FoodCamp2Counter.getText().toString());
                FoodCamp3 = Integer.parseInt(FoodCamp3Counter.getText().toString());
                FoodUpgrade1 = Integer.parseInt(FoodUpgrade1Counter.getText().toString());
                FoodUpgrade2 = Integer.parseInt(FoodUpgrade2Counter.getText().toString());
                FoodUpgrade3 = Integer.parseInt(FoodUpgrade3Counter.getText().toString());

                //get food income and show
                TotalFood = FoodCamp1 + (FoodCamp2 * 2) + (FoodCamp3 * 3) + (FoodUpgrade1 * 2) + (FoodUpgrade2 * 4) + (FoodUpgrade3 * 6);

                //These 3 options are what iv tried and do not work
                FoodIncomeCounter.setText(TotalFood.getText().toString());
                FoodIncomeCounter = Integer.parseInt(TotalFood.getText());
                String FoodIncomeCounter = String.valueOf(TotalFood);
                //------------------------------------------------------
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
FoodIncomeCounter.setText(TotalFood.getText().toString());
```

to

```
FoodIncomeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(TotalFood));
```

As getText() is a method on components like EditText, TextView, and not datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some educated guesses on the types of your fields, the following should work, as `TotalFood` is probably a number:

```
FoodIncomeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(TotalFood));
```

`getText()` is a method on `EditText`s but it doesn't work on numbers.